# MySQL date query

Tags: mysql

My table looks like this:

```
Name     Created
ganesh   2010-06-25 10:54:54 
vasant   2010-06-25 11:54:54 
charlie  2010-06-25 12:54:54 
sam      2010-06-25 13:54:54 
vasamtj  2010-06-25 01:54:54 
jack     2010-06-25 02:54:54 
nima     2010-06-24 10:54:54 
kumar    2010-06-24 10:54:54 
jay      2010-06-24 10:54:54 
paala    2010-06-23 10:54:54 
test1    2010-06-23 10:54:54 
jhon     2010-06-22 10:54:54
```

I want to show only today's entries, in where condition I don't want to add time:

```
SELECT  response FROM ost_ticket_response WHERE staff_id = 1 AND created ='now()'
```

this query checking with time also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table information is not complete but this query will do what you need:

```
SELECT *
FROM ost_ticket_response
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Created, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Instead of `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')` you can just pass string value `'2010-06-25'` from your code

Answer (score 1):

very rude, but:

```
SELECT response FROM ost_ticket_response WHERE staff_id = 1 AND created BETWEEN from_days(to_days(now())) AND from_days(to_days(now())+1)
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer that doesn't cause a full table scan (if correctly indexed).

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE Created >= date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),'%Y%m%d000000')
```

Answer (score 0):

This query fixed my problem:

```
SELECT count( response_id ) as cnt, staff_id FROM ost_ticket_response WHERE CAST( created AS Date ) = CURRENT_DATE( ) GROUP BY staff_id
```

Does this query have any drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
SELECT response FROM ost_ticket_response WHERE staff_id = 1 AND DATE(created) = CURDATE()
```